# Trim, LINQ style

Tags: c#

How do I improve the following?

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,0,5,7,0,6,0,0 };
list.Reverse();
list = list.SkipWhile(l => l == 0).ToList();
list.Reverse();
```

The goal is to trim trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reversing the list twice as well as creating a new List just to remove trailing zeros is very inefficient.

Running the below vs the other answers in a loop 10 million times shows this performs about 5 times faster than the accepted answer, and about 3 times faster than [`list.Take(list.FindLastIndex(item => item != 0) + 1).ToList();`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124537/trim-linq-style/124544#124544):

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0 };
for (int index = list.Count - 1; index >= 0 && list[index] == 0; index--)
{
    list.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

**Update (again)**

I've redone the measurements using varying inputs. Each answer's code is executed in a loop 10 million times. I've also moved the list creation out of the loop so it doesn't pollute what I'm trying to measure.

1 = [Reverse + SkipWhile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124539/56289)
2 = [For loop + RemoveAt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124546/56289)
3 = [Take + FindLastIndex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124544/56289)
4 = [GetRange + FindLastIndex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124539/56289)
5 = [For loop + FindLastIndex + RemoveRange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124550/56289)

Empty lists:

1. 2258 ms
2. **62 ms**
3. 844 ms
4. 488 ms
5. 138 ms

List of 100 non-zeros:

1. 52334 ms
2. **490 ms**
3. 34056 ms
4. 2170 ms
5. 665 ms

List of 100 non-zeros, 1 trailing zero:

1. 53420 ms
2. **1297 ms**
3. 34268 ms
4. 2360 ms
5. 1981 ms

List of 100 non-zeros, 100 trailing zeros:

1. 67423 ms
2. 12483 ms
3. 41153 ms
4. 8112 ms
5. **6958 ms**

List of 100 zeros:

1. 15711 ms
2. 10448 ms
3. 5404 ms
4. **5075 ms**
5. 5474 ms

**Code used for testing:**

```
class Program
{
    static List<int>[] lists;
    static List<int> nonZeros = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100));
    static List<int> zeros = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 100));
    const int max = 10000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> result = null;
        RecreateLists();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            result = Enumerable.Reverse(lists[i]).SkipWhile(x => x == 0).Reverse().ToList();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 1. {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        RecreateLists();
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            for (int index = lists[i].Count - 1; index >= 0 && lists[i][index] == 0; index--)
            {
                lists[i].RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 2. {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        RecreateLists();
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            result = lists[i].Take(lists[i].FindLastIndex(item => item != 0) + 1).ToList();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 3. {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        RecreateLists();
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            result = lists[i].GetRange(0, lists[i].FindLastIndex(x => x != 0) + 1);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 4. {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        RecreateLists();
        sw.Restart();
        int toRemove;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            toRemove = lists[i].FindLastIndex(item => item != 0) + 1;
            lists[i].RemoveRange(toRemove, lists[i].Count - toRemove);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 5. {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        lists = null;
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("\nComplete!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RecreateLists()
    {
        lists = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        lists = new List<int>[max];
        var combined = new List<int>(nonZeros);
        combined.AddRange(zeros);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            lists[i] = new List<int>(combined);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did your test code only use the sample input? I would be curious to see how it performs vs the Range/FLI with varying distributions of trailing zeros

Comment: @imsoconfused I've updated it now with various inputs.

Comment: Ahh. Good old fashion for loops. #nostalgia

Comment: The compared solutions are not comparable. Some of them mutate the list the others don't and return new lists. There should be two categories.

Answer (score 5):

`List.Reverse()` mutates the underlying list and returns `void`.
You do this twice.
It would be better to avoid unnecessary mutations.
You could do that by enumerating the values in reverse, using `Enumerable.Reverse(...)`, like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,0,5,7,0,6,0,0 };
list = Enumerable.Reverse(list).SkipWhile(x => x == 0).Reverse().ToList();
```

<del>Here, there are actually no mutations.</del><sup>*</sup> A new list is created from the original, by iterating from the end, skipping initial zeros, and putting values in the resulting list.

<sup>* So I thought. It seems `Enumerable.Reverse` copies values to a buffer. So no, this doesn't help much.</sup>

However, with the two "reverse" operations, this still feels pretty awkward. A simple, more straightforward, and probably faster way will be to get the range of values from the start until the last non-zero value:

```
list = list.GetRange(0, list.FindLastIndex(x =>x != 0) + 1);
```

As a side note, I changed the lambda variable from `l` to `x`, as `l` can be hard to read in some fonts. For this reason it's generally recommended to avoid `l` as a name in programs.

Answer (score 3):

eurotrash's method can be slightly improved by turning it into a `RemoveRange()`:

```
var toRemove = list3.FindLastIndex(item => item != 0) + 1;
list.RemoveRange(toRemove, list.Count - toRemove);
```

[Try It Online!](http://csharppad.com/gist/012bc4fd0dfd72163019214a7b02a6b7)

Output:

```
Reverse() took 3191 ticks.
eurotrash's method took 312 ticks.
eurotrash's method using RemoveRange() took 295 ticks.
The Take() method took 1749 ticks.
The GetRange() method took 330 ticks.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `list.Take(list.FindLastIndex(item => item != 0) + 1).ToList();` is slightly faster, as it does not reverse the list twice. (`Enumerable.Reverse` builds an internal array as a buffer)

[Try It Online!](http://csharppad.com/gist/f054e9fc65db2966c8c94b59d2acd3a1)